# Right way to use JWT auth token in React Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

I am using JWT for my React Redux app auth, also I have a plenty services that need my secret token.
I am saving JWT token in cookies, as well as in `user` object of my `common` reducer.
So every time I need to do request I am passing secret with `this.props.dispatch`

like this

```
this.props.dispatch({
    type: types.ADMIN_DATA_REQUEST,
    secret: this.props.user.token
});
```

this is my service

```
function getAdminData(secret) { 
    axios.get(config.api + api.adminData, {
        params: {
           secret
        }
    });
}
```

so I am interested what is right way to access JWT token, from redux store like I am doing or from cookies directly from service?

Answer (score 2):

This is where Redux Middleware comes in - basically it's a way of handling more complex types of actions. The most commonly used middleware is redux-thunk (https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and it allows you to dispatch functions that have access to redux state. So with redux-thunk you can store your secret in redux and do this:

```
const requestDataAction = () => ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    const secret = getState().user.secret;
    getAdminData( secret ).then( adminData => {
         dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_ADMIN_DATA", adminData });
    });
};
```

This is a function that returns a function, which is a bit confusing, but it does make sense. The outer function is the thing you call from your React component (after connecting it using mapPropsToDispatch). The inner one is the thunk that gets handled by the middleware, which injects the dispatch and getState functions for you.

The advantage of this is that you don't need your "secret" to be a prop in your React components because it's never used to render anything, it's only ever used in the action,

Comment: I am using `redux-saga` and passing secret from action

Comment: I think I can create selector for token and get token with this selector from my sagas

Comment: This seems somewhat inconvenient. If you do this, then you need to pass secret to EVERY service function.

Comment: Yes, a more convenient method is to get the secret during the app bootstrap, create an API object that knows about the secret, and then inject that API into your actions using middleware. That's my preferred solution but doesn't really fit what was asked.

Comment: Happy to create another answer if you're interested?

Answer (score 0):

Using axios you can create a new instance when you load your service file. So you will export this instance like this:

```
export const fetch = axios.create({
  baseURL: [YOUR SERVICE BASE URL]
})
```

Then in the same file, you can export a function to set the user token when you have it:

```
export function setUserSecret (secret) {
  fetch.defaults.params['secret'] = secret
}
```

So, everywhere you want to call a service you can do:

```
 import { fetch } from '[your_service_file.js]' 
 function getAdminData() { 
   fetch.get('[service path]');
 }
```